# How do I add tools for win 8 apps development to my VS 13?

Tags: c#, c++, windows, visual-studio-2013, windows-8.1

I've already instealled Windows 8.1 and VS 2013 (express) on my machine. Now I want to start building app for windows 8 (in either C# or C++). How do I add to my VS the SDK? even if I've already the VS 13 installed should I download [this](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=42670) MS executable size (over 4GB) and install it(it will be apart to my current installation, right?) or there's something to I just add support to my existing installation?

**EDIT::** [This is](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=42670) a **VS1 13** update version to get working win 8 apps development. The installation is apart from the VS 13 which target windows desktop only.

Comment: I'm pretty sure I remember reading that VS 2013 doesn't support creating Windows 8 apps; it only lets you target Windows 8.1. (Never mind, it is easily hacked.)

Comment: @CodyGray: Do you know if this http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=42670 will "update" my current VS 13 or install a new one apart from current? this still isn't clear to me.

Comment: Also, I think this VS 13 update make possible create win 8 apps on VS 13... I will downlaod it anyway.

Comment: I don't think it's an exact duplicate. This download link I put in the question is a working VS 13 version for create win 8 applications.